# Converting JSON to HTML Table on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, json, codeigniter

I have some issue how converting JSON to HTML table.

Now I'm using CI as framework for PHP.
But the thing is I just need to know how can I converting this [JSON type](http://www.adisurya.net/kurs-bca/get) to HTML table.

I just need to get those in the HTML table.

- the Currency name (e.g: AUD, USD)
- and the "Jual, Beli" number. (e.g: AUD Jual: 9987.1 Beli 9907.11)

I have try to decode that JSON to array, but I still didn't get it..

**Here's my array:**

```
stdClass Object (
  [Message] => stdClass Object (
    [Code] => 200 [Message] => request success 
  )
  [Data] => stdClass Object (
    [AUD] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 9987.11 [Beli] => 9907.11 
    )
    [CAD] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 10003.21 [Beli] => 9923.21 
    )
    [CHF] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 13236.59 [Beli] => 13136.59 
    )
    [CNY] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 1983.66 [Beli] => 1863.66 
    )
    [DKK] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 1934.2 [Beli] => 1854.2 
    )
    [EUR] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 14136.37 [Beli] => 14036.37 
    )
    [GBP] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 16638.24 [Beli] => 16538.24 
    )
    [HKD] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 1722.32 [Beli] => 1692.32 
    )
    [JPY] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 122.67 [Beli] => 119.27 
    )
    [NZD] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 9242.72 [Beli] => 9162.72 
    )
    [SAR] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 3578.14 [Beli] => 3498.14 
    )
    [SEK] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 1511.47 [Beli] => 1431.47 
    )
    [SGD] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 9481.43 [Beli] => 9461.43 
    )
    [USD] => stdClass Object (
      [Jual] => 13277 [Beli] => 13261 
    )
  )
  [LastUpdate] => 2017-04-12 23:00:08
  [ProcessingTime] => 0.0388939380646 
)
```

Comment: do json_decode($data,true) to get an array.

Comment: Have you considered building and returning the table html in the controller? Then simply return the html. From the looks of it the html would not be returning much more data (bytes) than the JSON. Codeigniter has a nice library for building tables too.

Comment: **I formatted the question A LOT**. Please, before you post your next question, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: thanks A LOT @LouysPatriceBessette im newbie on stackoverflow forum :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "json_decode" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and the "foreach" loop construct (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), both which work regardless of the PHP framework you use:

```
$json_object = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.adisurya.net/kurs-bca/get')) ;

echo '<table>' ;
foreach ( $json_object -> Data as $currency => $data ) {

    echo '<tr>' ;
    echo '<td>' . $currency . '</td>' ;
    echo '<td>' . $data -> Jual . '</td>' ;
    echo '<td>' . $data -> Beli . '</td>' ;
    echo '</tr>' ;

}
echo '</table>' ;
```

Comment: Yes, `</td>` and `</td>` are optional, but learning somebody to write less readable code is not a good idea.

Comment: It is optionnal *"in practice"* because modern browsers fix it. Still, it is needed to be valid HTML.

Comment: @YosafatKsatria my pleasure :)

Comment: but, i just dont get it with the multidimensional JSON data, any link that i can learn more? using w3schools and php.net still confusing me @sammysaglam

Comment: @YosafatKsatria sure, i am just outside right now, ill send you send you an easy to understand link about multidimensional JSON in a few hrs

Comment: @YosafatKsatria funnily enough, i couldnt find any good tutorials on this - maybe i just dont know where to look. but i was planning to write one anyways, so ill post it here once i finish writing

Comment: alright thanks a lot i really appreciate it @sammysaglam :))

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **AJAX** to retrieve this data. The I would suggest to use JSON.parse function first then use **each** loop in the page.

If your table

```
<table id="mytable"></table>
```

JQUERY AJAX CODE

```
$.get("http://www.adisurya.net/kurs-bca/get", function(data, status) {

  if (status == "success") {
    var loopdata = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(loopdata.data, function(i, item) {
      $('#mytable').append("<td>"+item+"</td>");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the AJAX CODE, but i need that just for showing, thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

You are converting JSON to object, not an array. The best way is to process JSON in your controller:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.adisurya.net/kurs-bca/get');
$data['json_array'] = json_decode($json, true);
```

and pass array to your view (change the name of your view):

```
$this->load->view('homepage', $data);
```

In your view you echo your table:

```
if (!empty($json_array)) {
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ($json_array as $currency => $currency_data) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$currency.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$currency_data['Jual'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$currency_data['Beli'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }    
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: thanks @shaggy but it seems A PHP Error was encountered <br> Undefined index: Beli and Illegal string offset 'Jual' what causes this?